# build path contains entries not specified by dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, m2e, buildpath

after importing a project into eclipse using m2e plugin, the build path contains entries not specified by the dependencies in the pom.xml file. Why?
The dependencies are shown in the following file.
`pom.xml:`

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>${spring.group}</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>${spring.group}</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>cglib</groupId>
   <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.5</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>
```

[Build path snapshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueypas4659n2s0o/build_path.png)

Edit:
When i posted this question, i were new to maven (and i still) but after reading about `transitive dependencies` i discovered the answer to my question.

Comment: Maybe you could be a tad more specific...?

Comment: Transitive dependencies?

Comment: yes i think that it's the case. I'm new to maven but after reading about transitive dependencies i understand now.